# Strong password in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application my password validation is only as

```
validates :password, :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

What am I supposed to do if I want my password to be more secure e.g., I want one capital and one or two special characters also to be in my password.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Done with adding security for passwords. Link refered : https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension

Answer (score 2):

There are several gems which validate passwords for strength.  Some check the password against arbitrary rules (mixed case, must have a digit, etc.).  Such rules are a proxy for entropy.  The [strong_password](http://rubygems.org/gems/strong_password) gem attempts to check more directly that the password has enough entropy.

It is preferable, when possible, to check entropy rather than rules such as mixed case, because many very good passwords that have a great deal of entropy will fail when checked against naive rules.

The strong_password gem is just one of many that check password strength.  I have not used it myself.  There's bound to be one that meets your needs.

Comment: The content behind that link requires an account!?